# Running ERDAS Imagine and ArcMap on same machine

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, erdas-imagine, arcgis-license-manager

ArcMap 10 and ERDAS 8.7 were already installed in my computer. But I want to open both programs at the same time. If ArcMap can open properly, ERDAS cann't open and vice versa, showed that following error (Fig.1).

[image: error while opening ERDAS]

IF I switch off ERDAS using License Manager Tools "LMTOOLS" (Fig.2), then ArcMap can open properly, If I switch off ArcMap using the same way above, ERDAS can open properly.

[image: in this case, ERDAS has switched off]

What is the reason for this problem and how do I fix it?

---

I've changed "any" into 27002 and both "this_host" and "son" into "user_PC" which is my computer full name. This time Erdas can open correctly, but arcgis cannot. The following image is a problem with opening ArcMap.

[image: error opening arcgis]

---

Here I'm adding some more photos of license files. When I opened both license files for arcgis and erdas, they look like this. First image is ArcGIS license file which is very similar to what @U2ros described above except "son". I think I can change 27001 into 27005 etc.

[image: arcgis 10 license file]

Next image is license file of Erdas. This looks totally different from what @U2ros described above. Here I'm fully confused which one is port number that I need to change to something like 27002.

[image: erdas license file].

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a collision in lmgrd process ports. If you edit the licence file in a text editor, you can change the default port that is used by the lmgrd process that uses the licence file. The licence file looks something like this:

```
--------------
START_LICENSE

SERVER 192.168.1.15 ESRI_SENTINEL_KEY=some_number_here 27006
```

Note the port used in this case is 27006. Open both licence files for erdas and arcgis and change one to 27001 and the other to 27002 for example, then restart both servers and reread the licences.